# what will be the MACRO functions RGBCOLOR(R, G, B) for [UIColor colorWithRed:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85 alpha:1]?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uicolor

I want to rewrite the color constant values using only the MACRO functions RGBCOLOR(R, G, B)

my code is:

```
#define kBasketEditedQuantityBorderColor  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85 alpha:1]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use C Macro functions in objective-C directly

```
#define RGBCOLOR(r, g, b) [UIColor colorWithRed:r/225.0f green:g/225.0f blue:b/225.0f alpha:1]

RGBCOLOR(25.0f, 25.0f, 114.0f)
```

I hope this will results your objective.

eg:
    [yourView setBackgroundColor:RGBCOLOR(25.0f, 25.0f, 114.0f)];

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8376/Function-like-Macros-vs-Inline-Functions

Comment: how should i set this valies Red:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85

Comment: your color range is from 0 to 1 right? I used here 1 to 255, so converted to 0-1 range while making UIColor object by dividing with 255.
You just rewrite the code like below,

#define RGBCOLOR(r, g, b) [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1]

Comment: and what bout the values 0.85?

Comment: Haha, you sure you should be programming? If you want to use 0.85 then just put 0.85 in it. `RGBCOLOR(0.85, 0.85, 0.85)`

Comment: @Fogmeister please read above comments carefully with edited code. I think you misunderstood. Or else please correct me on your behalf. thank you.

Comment: @imalvare sorry, was replying to the comment "and what bout the values 0.85?". I upvoted your answer.

Comment: i have tried to use this but its not working....:(    #define kBasketEditedQuantityBorderColor RGBACOLOR(0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 1.0)

Answer (score 2):

Example 1:

```
#define RGBCOLOR(R,G,B) [UIColor colorWithRed:R/255.2f green:G/255.2f blue:B/255.2f alpha:1];
```

-Usage: RGBCOLOR(243,243,243);

Example 2:

```
#define RGBCOLOR(R,G,B) [UIColor colorWithRed:R green:G blue:B alpha:1];
```

-Usage: RGBCOLOR (0.95,0.95,0.95);

two examples have the same result, depends on what value range you want to use 0-1 or 0-255

Comment: hi,
i have tried using:-
#define kBasketEditedQuantityBorderColor RGBCOLOR(0.85, 0.85, 0.85) [UIColor colorWithRed:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85 alpha:1]
But its giving me an error...:(

Comment: RGBCOLOR is a macro, to redefine macro u need declare RGBCOLOR before using.    i will give u examples

Comment: Example 1: 
#define RGBCOLOR(R,G,B) [UIColor colorWithRed:R green:G blue:B alpha:1];
#define kBasketEditedQuantityBorderColor RGBCOLOR(0.85,0.85,0.85);

Usage: button.backgroundColor = kBasketEditedQuantityBorderColor;

Comment: You should probably remove that `;` because then you could do something like `[RGBCOLOR(0, 0, 0) CGColor];`

Answer (score 0):

This can help you

```
#define HEXCOLOR(c) [UIColor colorWithRed:((c>>24)&0xFF)/255.0 green:((c>>16)&0xFF)/255.0 blue:((c>>8)&0xFF)/255.0 alpha:((c)&0xFF)/255.0];

// usage:
UIColor* c = HEXCOLOR(0xff00ffff);
```

Comment: what is the way to calculate it. Coz i have more to do like:-

Comment: 1) #define kBasketEditedQuantityBackgroundColor [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.95 blue:0.95 alpha:1]

Comment: #define kScanViewManualEntryButtonHighlightedBackgroundColor [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:1]

Comment: AND i have to do it in this format....:- #define kBasketEditedQuantityBorderColor RGBACOLOR(0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 1.0)

Comment: #define RGBACOLOR(r, g, b, a) [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1];

usage ->>> RGBACOLOR(0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 1.0)

Comment: how will i convert 0.85 to decimal number?

Comment: do u want use decimal or float numbers ??

Comment: for Decimals use this #define RGBCOLOR(r, g, b) [UIColor colorWithRed:r/225.0f green:g/225.0f blue:b/225.0f alpha:1]

RGBCOLOR(25.0f, 25.0f, 114.0f) <-- from 0 to 255

Comment: i have used this#define kBasketEditedQuantityBorderColor RGBACOLOR(0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 1.0)

Comment: The RGB macro takes 0 - 255. This looks like a wrong colour.

[UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.95 blue:0.95 alpha:1] does not match RGBACOLOR(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1.0) 

when i used this code then color is not matching